# Why does Arc::try_unwrap() cause a panic?

Tags: error-handling, rust, smart-pointers, reference-counting

I'm writing a simple chat server which broadcasts messages to all the clients connected.

The code might look terrible, since I'm a beginner. Peers are not used anywhere yet, since I want to pass it to `handle_client` function as well, so when data will be available in stream and read successfully, I want to broadcast it over all the clients connected. I understand this is not a good approach, I'm just trying to understand how can I do things like this in general.

```
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::Write;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::Arc;

fn handle_client(arc: Arc<TcpStream>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = Arc::try_unwrap(arc).unwrap();

    stream.write(b"Welcome to the server!\r\n")?;
    println!("incomming connection: {:?}", stream);

    std::thread::spawn(move || -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let peer_addr = stream.peer_addr()?;
        let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(stream);
        let mut buf = String::new();

        loop {
            let bytes_read = reader.read_line(&mut buf)?;
            if bytes_read == 0 {
                println!("client disconnected {}", peer_addr);
                return Ok(());
            }

            buf.remove(bytes_read - 1);
            println!("{}: {}", peer_addr, buf);

            buf.clear();
        }
    });

    Ok(())
}

fn start() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:1111")?;
    println!("listening on {}", listener.local_addr()?.port());

    let mut peers: Vec<Arc<TcpStream>> = vec![];

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let arc = Arc::new(stream);

        peers.push(arc.clone());
        handle_client(arc.clone()).unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    start()
}
```

It compiles fine, but `let mut stream = Arc::try_unwrap(arc).unwrap();` in the `handle_client` function panics. What am I doing wrong? Why is it panicking?

Comment: Could you debug and see the output of Arc::try_unwrap(arc) ?

Comment: trying to also find a debugger for it, since I'm doing it blindly (wasn't able to find any debuggers for rust).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it panicking?

You are calling `unwrap` on a `Result::Err`. The `Err` comes from `try_unwrap` failing on the `Arc`.

> What am I doing wrong?

Unwrapping an `Arc` will *move* its value and take ownership of it. This fails because there are three clones of the same `Arc`:

- one in the main loop which is still in scope
- one in the `peers` vector
- the one that you are trying to unwrap inside `handle_client`.

The other two clones would become invalid if Rust allowed you to unwrap and move the value.
Instead of unwrapping the value you can use `Arc`'s  `Deref` implementation to borrow it:

```
let stream: &TcpStream = &arc;
```

Since you are now borrowing the value from the `Arc`, you need to move the scope of the `arc` variable inside the new thread, otherwise the borrow checker won't be able to ensure that it lives as long as the thread:

```
fn handle_client(arc: Arc<TcpStream>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::thread::spawn(move || -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut stream: &TcpStream = &arc;
        stream.write(b"Welcome to the server!\r\n")?;

        let peer_addr = stream.peer_addr()?;
        let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(stream);
        let mut buf = String::new();

        // ... 
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, if I comment the `peers.push(arc.clone())`, it still panics. What I found out is that, after removing `.clone` it works fine.

Comment: There are **two** other references. The other is the `arc` variable inside the loop, whose scope is until the end of the loop. When you remove the `clone`, you instead move the variable, so it is no longer alive in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It says in [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap)

> Returns the contained value, if the `Arc` has exactly one strong
>   reference.
>
> Otherwise, an [`Err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) is returned with the same `Arc` that was passed in.
>
> This will succeed even if there are outstanding weak references.

([weak reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Weak.html))

Your code will work fine with one strong and many weak references.

```
let mut peers: Vec<Weak<TcpStream>> = vec![];

for stream in listener.incoming() {
    let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
    let arc = Arc::new(stream);
    peers.push(Arc::downgrade(&arc));
    handle_client(arc).unwrap();
}
```

One thing to note about the weak references: if you unwrap your one strong reference, you will not able to use weak references.

Comment: Thanks for the explaining, I'll practice more on this. It's all clear now! :)