# Unwrap and access T from an Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>

Tags: rust, smart-pointers, dereference

I am trying to solve some Leetcode problems with Rust. However, I ran into some difficulties with LeetCode's `TreeNode` implementation.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// TreeNode data structure
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        TreeNode {
            val,
            left: None,
            right: None,
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to do an inorder traversal, how to unwrap the `TreeNode`'s `Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>` object, access its `.val` `.left` `.right` and pass them as inputs into a recursive function?

I have tried:

```
pub struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn inorder_traversal(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut ret: Vec<i32> = vec![];
        match root {
            Some(V) => Solution::helper(&Some(V), &mut ret),
            None => (),
        }

        ret
    }

    fn helper(node: &Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, ret: &mut Vec<i32>) {
        match node {
            None => return,
            Some(V) => {
                // go to the left branch
                Solution::helper(
                    (*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
                        .into_inner()
                        .left,
                    ret,
                );
                // push root value on the vector
                ret.push(Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err().into_inner().val);
                // go right branch
                Solution::helper(
                    (*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
                        .into_inner()
                        .right,
                    ret,
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99b7fd163ad8179d1d63e7383b1a99dc))

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:42:21
   |
42 | /                     (*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
43 | |                         .into_inner()
44 | |                         .left,
   | |_____________________________^ expected reference, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::option::Option<std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<TreeNode>>>`
              found type `std::option::Option<std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<TreeNode>>>`
help: consider borrowing here
   |
42 |                     &(*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
43 |                         .into_inner()
44 |                         .left,
   |
```

But if I try the suggestion, it complains as well:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of an `Rc`
  --> src/lib.rs:42:22
   |
42 |                     &(*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of an `Rc`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of data in a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:42:22
   |
42 |                     &(*Rc::try_unwrap(Rc::clone(V)).unwrap_err())
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      cannot move out of data in a `&` reference
   |                      cannot move
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Unwrap** and access `T` from an `Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>`

You **really** don't want to try to remove the value from the `Option`, the `Rc` or the `RefCell` via `unwrap` / `try_unwrap` / `into_inner`. Instead, pattern match on the `Option` and then call `borrow` on the `RefCell` to get a reference to the `T`.

Additionally:

1. Use `if let` instead of a `match` statement when you only care about one arm.
2. Variables use `snake_case`. `V` is not an appropriate name.
3. There's no need to use a struct here, or to define the helper function publicly. A plain function and a nested function are simpler and exposes less detail.
4. There's no need to provide an explicit type when constructing `ret`.

```
pub fn inorder_traversal(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    fn helper(node: &Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, ret: &mut Vec<i32>) {
        if let Some(v) = node {
            let v = v.borrow();

            helper(&v.left, ret);
            ret.push(v.val);
            helper(&v.right, ret);
        }
    }

    let mut ret = vec![];

    if let Some(v) = root {
        helper(&Some(v), &mut ret);
    }

    ret
}
```

Personally, I'm not a fan of being forced to construct the `Some`, so I'd probably reorganize the code, which also allows me to stick it as a method on `TreeNode`:

```
impl TreeNode {
    pub fn inorder_traversal(&self) -> Vec<i32> {
        fn helper(node: &TreeNode, ret: &mut Vec<i32>) {
            if let Some(ref left) = node.left {
                helper(&left.borrow(), ret);
            }

            ret.push(node.val);

            if let Some(ref right) = node.right {
                helper(&right.borrow(), ret);
            }
        }

        let mut ret = vec![];
        helper(self, &mut ret);
        ret
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why does Arc::try_unwrap() cause a panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53691655/155423)

Comment: just wondering. For the purpose of this exercise `TreeNode` could be written using just `Box` instead `Rc<RefCell<..>>` right? If the answer is yes, is this version better for trees? Please let me know if this comment worth a brand new question.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda could be? Sure, as far as I can see. "Better" isn't a well-formed question. They have different capabilities and tradeoffs. If you need a capability that only one form provides, then that one is better for your case.

Comment: I see. About the "Better" part of the question, sorry I don't  explain my self, I was meaning in the context of this very same exercise. I have seen this  exercise in sites like LeetCode and I have seen the same data structure implemented in Rust using `Box` or `Rc/RefCell`. I am relatively new to Rust and things like that caught my attention. In this exercise, there is no need for share values or mutate the node values (the perfect use case for Rc-RefCell), so, perhaps due to me having so little experience with Rust I was missing something, perhaps related with performance,  I don't know.

Comment: I investigate further, and found this article, about inner-mutability, where you can find an example of a Graph implementation. In a Graph, one same node can be adjacent to several nodes, so in this case using Rc with RefCell have more sense since two or more nodes might "share" the same neighbors. In a tree (binary in this case), one and only one node can be either the left or the right child of a parent, so, in my humble opinion using `Box` over `Rc/RefCell` *for trees* is less error prone and better for clarity and readability.

https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/08/interior-mutability

Comment: @RaydelMiranda yes, I'd also probably use a `Box` for this problem.