# How to invoke get function on Ref<HashMap<K, V>> and return Option<Ref<T>>?

Tags: rust

I have data that can be divided into several categories and each category can divided into several sub-types. I save the data as `HashMap<Type1, HashMap<Type2, Data>>`.

I need to get a mutable reference of different categories at the same time, so the definition becomes `HashMap<Type1, RefCell<HashMap<Type2, Data>>>`.

How do I implement the `get` function?

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo<T> {
    data: HashMap<u32, RefCell<HashMap<u32, T>>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn get_mut(&self, k: u32, k2: u32) -> Option<RefMut<T>> {
        unimplemented!() // Help me >_<
    }
}
```

The key question is when I call `HashMap::get_mut` function on `RefMut<HashMap<K,V>>`, it sees that there is not way to return `Option<RefMut<V>>`

```rust
use std::cell::RefMut;
use std::collections::HashMap;

//I can check twice if the map contains k, but it's inefficient.
fn get_mut<V>(map: RefMut<HashMap<u32, V>>, k: u32) -> Option<RefMut<V>> {
    if map.contains_key(&k) {
        Some(RefMut::map(map, |map| map.get_mut(&k).unwrap()))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29401626/155423) and [Unwrap and access T from an Option<Rc<RefCell<T>>>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54012660/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was a method to do exactly what you are hoping for, but [it was removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27746). However, I think this is a use case that they might not have considered, so it might not be a bad idea to try pinging the issue.

Otherwise, here is a somewhat inefficient solution that will work:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo<T> {
    data: HashMap<u32, RefCell<HashMap<u32, T>>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn get_entry(&self, k: u32, k2: u32) -> Option<RefMut<T>> {
        self.data
            .get(&k)
            .map(|inner| inner.borrow_mut())
            .filter(|x| x.contains_key(&k2))
            .map(|x| RefMut::map(x, |y| y.get_mut(&k2).unwrap()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I visit the link you provided and find [unsafe code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27746#issuecomment-172899746) maybe the correct solution for me. Although it's really difficult to understand.